# Why is a clean install of Windows recommended after hardware changes?

Tags: windows-10, performance, clean-install

I haven't clean installed Windows 10 since I installed it about three years ago, and since then I've upgraded every component apart from my SSD.

While I think I've done a good job of keeping it clean, in a few games (GTA V, Warzone) I've noticed that my usage for all my components barely goes above 50%, but I still get poor performance. On forums, the consensus seems to be to clean install Windows to solve this issue.

I have 1 SSD and 3 HDDs and I just bought a new SSD. I plan to do a clean install of Windows on this new SSD and leave my other drives untouched. My main question is in the post title, but it leads on to this: **will I still see the benefits of the clean install if I leave my other drives untouched?** Or must I do a complete wipe of my data?

Of course, if my performance doesn't improve, I'll start formatting my drives, but I'd like to understand the processes better.

Comment: I've always considered the practise of clean installing Windows every 5 minutes to be an ancient interwebz meme still hanging over from WinXP days, or even before.

Comment: If "every component" includes the motherboard then an OEM license would almost certainly not be valid any longer. The PC would be like the famous ship sailed by the hero Theseus in a great battle, kept in a harbor as a museum piece, and as the years went by some of the wooden parts began to rot and were replaced by new ones; then, after a century or so, every part had been replaced.

Comment: I have the same installation from a PC I built back in 2004.  I simply migrate the installation, change the license, as I get new PCs.   Seems like you want us to prove a negative.  I have no performance issues on any of my machines.